# Easy Trig - Move an object in a position

Tags: c#, vector, trigonometry, direction

I know this is quite easy trigonomety, however I was never introducted to vectors etc, and I'm at a loss understanding how this works.

Given an object at point XY, and a direction N, how do you move that object in that direction?

Also, given am object at point XY, and a destination at point XY, how do you move an object towards the destination?

I understand there is some need for adding vectors etc.

Could somebody please refer me to some easy material to digest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Given an object at point XY, and a direction N, how do you move that object in that direction?*

If your point is (X,Y) and your direction is a vector (NX, NY), you simply add those two. Now your object is at the position (X + NX, Y + NY).

*Also, given am object at point XY, and a destination at point XY, how do you move an object towards the destination?*

If your source point is (SX, SY) and your destination point is (DX, DY), you usually move the object along (SX + t * (DX - SX), SY + t * (DY - SY)) with t = 0..1

Answer (score 3):

Given a point x,y, an angle n and a distance d, you calculate the new position like this:

```
x = x + cos(n) * d
y = y + sin(n) * d
```

Given the point x,y, the destination x2,y2 and the distance to move d, the distance between the points is:

```
dt = ((x2 - x)^2 + (y2 - y)^2) ^ 0.5
```

The new position is:

```
x = x + (x2 - x) * (d / dt)
y = y + (y2 - y) * (d / dt)
```